# How can I add an independent controller method with a view for confirming delete?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When a resource is to be deleted in Rails' CRUD, it is standard to display a modal/popup to get user's confirmation, then call the controller method `destroy`. This is done by something like this:

```
link_to "Delete", resource_path(resource), method: :delete, confirm: "Are you sure?"
```

Going against this, I want to have the confirmation as an independent view page with a dedicated controller method (let's say `confirm_destroy`). Then deletion would follow two steps of method calls, in parallel with when a resource is created or updated:

- `new` → `create`
- `edit` → `update`
- `confirm_destroy` → `destroy`

I can do this relatively easily, but there is a minor difficulty such that I have to manually define the routes path for `confirm_destroy` while other paths can be done with a single `resource(s)` method.

Am I on the wrong track? What is the best way to deal with such case?

Comment: You could try to create your own custom `resources_with_confirm_destroy :name_of_the_resource` which would include a `get :confirm_destroy, on: :member` and then call the regular `resources :name_of_the_resource`

Comment: Also, if you think adding the `confirm_destroy` in your paths is a minor difficulty, then you will be surprised when you will have to replace all of your `link_to 'Delete', some_path(), method: :delete` links to use `confirm_delete_some_path()`

Answer (score 2):

I think best way is to create new route and new action, because it's custom action. By default resource includes only :destroy